# I'm having trouble understanding the sentance どうだい、きに いったかい

Tags: translation, parts-of-speech

What I'm reading says that **どうだい、きに いったかい** translates to "Well, do you like it?" The parts individually are translated as

> どうだい - How about
>
> きに - I can't figure out what **きに** means at all. Unless he is talking about trees.
>
> いったかい - you said?

Which kind of makes sense that he wants her to tell him what she thinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is you are compartmentalizing the words in the sentence incorrectly.

きに　does not mean anything in itself. The phrase you're looking for is "気に入る" (ki ni iru) which means "to like" or "to be pleased with".

~かい - this marks a yes/no question.

気に入ったかい？ = do you like it? (ki ni itta kai?)

どうだい、きに いったかい? = Well, do you like it?

Answer (score -2):

きに いったかい is a conjugated form of 気に入る (ki ni iru) which means to be fond of something, or in your case to like, or be pleased with.  I'm guessing いったかい is a shortened version of いったくない。

Comment: I think Darren's answer for いったかい is better than mine :)

Comment: かい is a question indicating particle, so 気に入ったかい＝気に入ったか in terms of meaning.